# How to find location of azure cli in windows

Tags: windows, azure

I installed azure cli in windows. But I am unable to find its location. I do have a folder named .azure but I can't find anything else. Is there any way to find out where it is installed? like in anaconda

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Windows [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) you can use:

```
where az
```

should return something similar to:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Azure/CLI2/wbin/az.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did not work for me however get-command did
get-command az

You can also do
$(get-command az).Path or
$(get-command az).Source

Comment: `where.exe az` works in CMD and PowerShell. The reason `where` doesn't work in Powershell is because that is already an alias for `Where-Object`, so there is a conflict. Easy enough fix by just adding the `.exe` extension.

Answer (score 1):

### AZURE CLI does NOT Install Another Command Prompt

The confusion Microsoft creates is they do not tell you in clear language what Azure CLI is. **Azure CLI is just a bunch of commands it adds to your Windows or Mac device you can access in any command prompt within your operating system.**

*It is NOT installing another command prompt.*

You do not need another command prompt. On Windows there are as many as half a dozen already installed you can access that pretty much all do the same thing, and all of which allow you to access the new **"Azure CLI Commands"**.

Want proof? First see if you have any of these command prompts installed on your Windows PC:

**A FEW OF THE AVAILABLE COMMAND PROMPT IN WINDOWS 10/11**

```
DEFAULT COMMAND PROMPT in Windows
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe


Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022 (if you are a programmer)
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat


Windows Powershell
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

### HOW TO CHECK IF YOU HAVE AZURE CLI

1. Open up any of the command prompts above
2. Type: "az version"
3. You should get something back like the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.47.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.47.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.8",
  "extensions": {}
}
```

I wish computer people would describe more clearly what all the crazy stuff they build actually does...it would make things so much easier!